# How can i get http request and response timings in perl selenium webdriver for performance testing

Tags: perl, selenium-webdriver, performance-testing

I am looking for the page loading times in ***Selenium Remote Driver***. I am using ***perl***. 
I have tried ***Firebug*** with ***NetExport***, but how can i sync these results with selenium tests?
I can get the time for each test case by adding timestamps before and after execution. But I want the client side time.

I don't want to use jmeter here.

Answer (score 0):

There are pros and cons of checking performance at client side & Server side.

Client side: Almost accurate....but it doesn't consider the Page loading time and timing starts once the page is loaded completely.

Server Side: Easy to generate...but timings also include the network latency.

So selection among both criterion is purely on requirement basis.

Coming to the point of Client side notifying the timings...i would suggest you to go JavaScript way along with Selenium (C# & JavaScript code snippet)

```
    IJavaScriptExecutor js = (IJavaScriptExecutor) driver;
    js.ExecuteScript("SetTimefunction();");
    // Your Automation Code goes Here
    js.ExecuteScript("return CalculateTime();");
```

Here is how your JavaScript code in the page should look like:

```
//Global variable in your page for start time of execution.
var Start_Global_Time;

//Sets the start time of your execution
function SetTimefunction(){
 Start_Global_Time=new Date();
}

//Calculate Difference between the Exec & Start Time
function CalculateTime(){
 var Exec_end_time=new Date();
 return Exec_end_time-Start_Global_Time;
}
```